# C# Remove XML elements based on attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

Would really appreciate some help with this one. The below code removes an element from an XML if it contains the Deleted = true attribute. This works perfectly fine except it only removes the first match. I would like it to remove ALL the Object elements with the attribute condition Deleted = true

```
        public static string TestMethod1(string xmlpath)
    
        XmlDocument xmlfile = new XmlDocument();
        xmlfile.Load(xmlpath);
        string xmlcontents = xmlfile.InnerXml;

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlcontents);

        doc.Descendants("Object")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Deleted").Value == "true").FirstOrDefault()
            .Remove();

        doc.Save(outputpath);
        string docstring = doc.ToString();
        return docstring;
```

Comment: can you please add sample xml

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
doc.Descendants("Object")
   .Where(x=> x.Attribute("Deleted").Value == "true")
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately this throws an exception due to XElement object not having a ToList() method

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .FirstOrDefault() from my code resolved my issue.